# Show multiple MAX results

Tags: sql, sqlite

Suppose I have a table as follows:

```
loan:
no  | credit
-------------
L1  | 600
L2  | 550
L3  | 800
L4  | 800
L5  | 700
```

If I want to find the max loan I can simply do this:

```
SELECT MAX(l.no)
FROM loan l
WHERE l.credit = (SELECT MAX(l.credit) from loan l)
```

But this would only return me one loan. Is there a way to display both `L3` and `L4` without making a complicated query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why you put a "MAX" in the select query?

```
--delete the MAX here, or else only one record would be fetched.
SELECT l.no
FROM loan l
WHERE l.credit = (SELECT MAX(l.credit) from loan l)
```

Comment: Yeah, sure, just post the same answer as me 3 minutes later and get an upvote. Why not...

Comment: My bad, I was googling about some other question that involved finding the 'second largest' value and it had MAX in the SELECT.

Comment: @fancyPants Oops... sorry, just now I was in the "Post your answer" and didn't notice you've already post an answer...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, just don't use an aggregate function without a group by if you want to have more than one row.

```
SELECT no, credit
FROM loan l
WHERE l.credit = (SELECT MAX(l.credit) from loan l)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Group by credit

Something like below

SELECT l.no
FROM loan l
WHERE l.credit = (SELECT MAX(l.credit) from loan l)
Group by credit;

Comment: yes, do not aggregate and use group by, hope that's better. :)